# Desktop Dungeon bug on unlocking Siege of Lothlorien?

Tags: technical-issues, desktop-dungeons-2010

The description says that I'll be able to play the Siege of Lothlorien when I gain access to all playable races. I have unlocked all the races and classes (although not yet finished everything with them) and yet I still don't have it available. Is this a bug?

[image: Game selection screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same thought.  But actually the three "classes" on the far right are race/class combinations, and so you have to unlock all three of them before the siege of lothlorien will become unlocked.  Better explanation containing spoilers below

> Those three classes are the "monster" classes: Gorgon, Half-Dragon, and Vampire.  When you select them, your choice of races on the top is ignored, and they are colored gray the same as the other races, so they are effectively both a race and a class.

Comment: OHHHH! didn't know about that spoiler. now im fired up to get them! But yeah, thanks, i actually thought no one was gonna answer and went ahead and checked their forums. thanks for the reply then